# Bisection Search problem - MIT Intro to CS Problem Set

Tags: python, search, bisection

I have to find the best rate of savings to achieve a down payment on a $1M house in
36 months.

Here are the values that are predetermined:
1. Your semi­annual raise is .07 (7%)
2. Your investments have an annual return of 0.04 (4%)
3. The down payment is 0.25 (25%) of the cost of the house
4. The cost of the house that you are saving for is $1M.

This is also directly from the problem set:
Because we are searching for a value that is in principle a float, we are going to limit ourselves to two decimals of accuracy (i.e., we may want to save at 7.04% ­­ or 0.0704 in decimal – but we are not
going to worry about the difference between 7.041% and 7.039%). This means we can search for an
integer​ between 0 and 10000 (using integer division), and then convert it to a decimal percentage
(using float division) to use when we are calculating the ​current_savings​ after 36 months. By using
this range, there are only a finite number of numbers that we are searching over, as opposed to the
infinite number of decimals between 0 and 1. This range will help prevent infinite loops. The reason we
use 0 to 10000 is to account for two additional decimal places in the range 0% to 100%. Your code
should print out a decimal (e.g. 0.0704 for 7.04%).

```
#best savings rate in 3 years

annual_salary = float(input("Enter your annual salary: "))
total_cost = 1000000
semi_annual_raise = 0.07
portion_down_payment = 0.25*total_cost
r = 0.04

low = 0
high = 10000
portion_saved = int((high+low)/2)
steps = 0
current_savings = 0

months = 0
salary_increase_months = 0
while(months <= 36):
    portion_saved = portion_saved/1000
    #checks every 6th iteration to add the semi annual raise
    if(salary_increase_months == 6):
        annual_salary += annual_salary*semi_annual_raise
        salary_increase_months = 0
    current_savings += current_savings*(r/12) + portion_saved*(annual_salary/12)
    salary_increase_months += 1
    months += 1

    #bisection code
    if(months == 36):
        if current_savings < portion_down_payment:
            low = portion_saved
            months = 0
        elif current_savings > portion_down_payment:
            high = portion_saved
            print('Best savings rate:', portion_saved)
            print('Steps in bisection search:', steps)
            break
        else:
            print('It is not possible to pay the down payment in three years.')
            break
        portion_saved = (low + high)/2
        steps += 1
```

These are test cases that we are given:

Test Case 1

```
Enter the starting salary:​ 150000
Best savings rate:​ 0.4411
Steps in bisection search:​ 12
```

Test Case 2

```
Enter the starting salary:​ 300000
Best savings rate:​ 0.2206
Steps in bisection search:​ 9
```

Test Case 3

```
Enter the starting salary:​ 10000
It is not possible to pay the down payment in three years.
```

For the first input this is what I get

```
Enter your annual salary: 150000
Best savings rate: 5.000000000000001e-105
Steps in bisection search: 2
```

I've just been having a lot of trouble understanding what I'm doing wrong and I wanted someone to help me out and point out what I'm doing wrong. I want to know the solution, but with some explanation too. Obviously I can look up other peoples' solutions but I want to understand what I'm doing wrong because I'm trying to learn.

Comment: with while(months <= 36): portion_saved = portion_saved/1000, you lower it 36 times by 10^3, so of course it's in the 10^-105. At least that line is wrong